# Проблема с наследованием div, при добавление еще 1 diva свойства предыдущего не работают

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

```css
*{
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .main{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" >
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="testl.css">
        <title>test</title>
         </head>
        <body>
            <div class="main">
                <div class="foto_left">
                    <div class="foto_1">
                       1
                    </div>
                    <div class="foto_2">
                       2
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="foto_right">
                    <div class="foto_3">
                        3
                    </div>
                    <div class="foto_4">
                        4
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: если чесно, не понятно что не так) попробуйте сделать так: 1) у меня так работает. 2) а вот так не работает. почему?

Comment: только Вы не в комментах это всё пишите, а добавьте нормально в вопрос, поясните, что именно не так

Comment: Если Вы про то, что display:flex не наследуется на вложенные блоки, то он не наследуемый ))) Задайте для фото общий класс .foto и пропишите им flex